# Print function type mismatch in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

> I faced runtime error while printing by the print function

```
print "knvc"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `print` Sub in native/plain VBScript running under the c/wscript.exe script hosts (other hosts - e.g. QTP - may provide one). Use `WScript.Echo` instead.

**Update wrt comment:**

To demonstrate VBScript's console output (using cscript in a 'dos box'; starting the script from your editor or doubleclick from explorer may run it via wscript.exe, then you will get a nasty surprise):

26337387.vbs

```
Option Explicit

Dim sInp : sInp = "Hyderabad"
Dim i
For i = 1 to Len(sInp)
    '  print mid(d,i,1) ' no native print in VBScript.
    WScript.Echo Mid(sInp, i, 1) ' each character on its own line
Next
For i = 1 to Len(sInp)
    WScript.StdOut.Write Mid(sInp, i, 1) ' each character on the same line
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 26337387.vbs
H
y
d
e
r
a
b
a
d
Hyderabad
```

Comment: thanks,& I need to print in single editor at a time,is it possible ?

Comment: @knvchowdary What do you mean by "print in single editor at a time"?

Comment: my input is "ABCDEF",o/p is 'A' can display in 1st line,'B' can display in 2nd line & so on,display in one time

Comment: @knvchowdary - still not sure what you mean, but I did update my answer.

Comment: thanks,U did well,my requirement is,o/p is what U done,but all will display at a time,not by clicking "OK" button in window.